# pyinstaller устанавливает лишние модули

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe

Когда я использую pyinstaller на одном скрипте с основного пк exe весит 120Мб-200Мб, но как у меня пропал доступ к основному пк и мне пришлось компилировать на другом, этот же скрипт после компиляции начинал весить 500Мб-900Мб
Я думаю, что это связано с установкой лишних библиотек которых не присутствует в коде, например во время компиляции замечал строку tenserflow Хотя в скрипте она не используется ( все модули которые используются с ней никак не связаны)

Comment: А скрипт написан в виртуальном окружении? Не может тянуть все библиотеки?

Comment: Вопрос в том использовалось ли виртуальное окружение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, сформулируйте вопрос. Сейчас не очень удобно ответить вам, потому что непонятно, собственно, на что

Comment: Нет, не использовалось